# Finding dependancies of unmanaged c++ dll referenced in C#

Tags: c#, c++, .net, dll, unmanaged

I have a C# winforms application that uses a dll that I wrote in c++ as unmanaged code.  On 4 test computers the program works just as it's supposed to.  On 8 test computers I get an error when running the program.

> Unable to load DLL "myUnmanaged.dll". The specified module could not be found.

The dll in question is located in the same directory as the c# exe.  Visual studio is set to copy the file to the location when "compiling" the c# exe.

Since the program works on some computers but not others, I'm guessing that the computers that the application works on have some dll's already on them that are required for my program to work.

I will note that my unmanaged dll includes calls to another dll from a windows kit called SetupApi.dll.  Getting Visual Studio to properly reference this dll required pointing VS directly to it's lib file to get my dll to compile.  All of the computers that run my program correctly have setupapi.dll located in the windows\system32 directory.  Some of the computers that don't run my program correctly also have setupapi.dll located in the windows\system32 directory.  For a test i put the setupapi.dll in the same directory as my c# exe and retested on the computers that didn't work and the result was the same.

How do i find out what file(s)/dependencies I'm missing that is preventing my app from working on some of the computers?

I'm using VS express 2013 for writing the software.  It's missing some of the functionality that the pro version has.  One solution was to generate an MSI file and it would have the dependencies included with it.  But that's a pro feature that I don't have access to.

Any assistance in this matter will be greatly appreciated.

Information regarding 32-bit/64-bit:
Both the c# application and the unmanaged c++ dll are built in 32-bit(x86).  3 of the test computers that the program work on are 64-bit win OS (vista 64-bit, win7 64-bit, win8.1 64bit) and one of the test computers that the program works on is Win7 32-bit.  The computers that my application doesn't work on include 32-bit and 64-bit machines.  Because of this i'm fairly certain that my problem is not related to the bitness of the OS.

Comment: Please use .net reflactor or dependancy walker make sure you are using x86 or x64 version according to what you need

Comment: I ran dependency walker on a test computer that worked and a test computer that didn't work.  The files listed as not being found were the same on both computers.  I'll dig into .net reflactor and DW more and see If i can find the problem.  Thanks for pointing out those tools.

Comment: Try the process  monitor from the System internal, it can tell you which DLL is not found

Comment: I looked into using process monitor.  After several hours of learning about filters i still wasn't able to find the answer.  I am glad that it was recommended because it appears to be a very powerful tool once learned. I did eventually find the answer with Dependency Walker.  Thanks to Gilad and Matt for their help.

Comment: Dependency Walker is no longer dependable.  You should use Process Monitor or the Fusion Logging mechanism to help track this down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Please use .net reflactor or dependancy walker make sure you are using
>   x86 or x64 version according to what you need – Gilad

This comment to the original question ended up having the solution in it.  I used dependency walker, as recommended, to find the missing dll.